# Custom CSS for particular Wordpress Menu Item

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to change the CSS of `li ul li`   from following code by Custom CSS, I have written a custom class for them and tried to assign it by WP-ADMIN but it is inefective.

```
<li id="menu-item-10088" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children submenu hover"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/">Company</a>
<ul class="sub-menu " style="display: block; overflow: hidden; height: 31.90023458481924px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <li id="menu-item-10817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10818" class="aboutus menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/management-team/">Management Team</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-11137" class="aboutus menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/#company-2">Vision</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10820" class="aboutus menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom last-item"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/#company-3">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
<span class="menu-toggle"></span></li>
```

I added custom class as following and mentioned it in respective WP Menu item

```
#Header .sub-menu .aboutus li ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

but it didn't work , all I need is to make width of the Menu items mentioned in above code as 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="sub-menu " style="display: block; overflow: hidden; height: 31.90023458481924px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <li id="menu-item-10817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10818" class="aboutus menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/management-team/">Management Team</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-11137" class="aboutus menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/#company-2">Vision</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10820" class="aboutus menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom last-item"><a href="http://www.example.com/company/#company-3">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
```

As per your HTML , `li` is your parent `li` ,  `.sub-menu` is your `ul` and child `li` has class `.aboutus` , so it should be like below

```
#Header li .sub-menu li.aboutus {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Even the following will work good, as you need not refer `li` if `sub-menu` will be present only in nested `li`

```
 #Header .sub-menu li.aboutus {
        font-weight: normal;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        }
```